# Add healthcheck in Keycloak Docker Swarm service

Tags: docker, keycloak, docker-swarm, redhat-sso

What's the best way to test the health of [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org) configured as cluster deployed as docker swarm service?

I tried the below healthcheck for testing availability in Keycloak service descriptor:

```
   healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "curl http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/[realm_name]"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 10
      start_period: 1m
```

Are there more things to check for?
Couldn't find the documentation for this.

Comment: check this jira https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-1578, other options discussed

Comment: You need to add the `--fail` option to your curl command if you want it to fail when it receives something other than a 200

Answer (score 3):

With Keycloak 21 new micro base image is [used](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/commit/610e3044adea39003fdb256585a74d9adea2cd12), so 'curl' no longer included in Image so healthcheck will not work anymore.

If Keycloak configured without HTTPS my workaround is this:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 3<>/dev/tcp/localhost/8080

echo -e "GET /auth/health/ready HTTP/1.1\nhost: localhost:8080\n" >&3

timeout --preserve-status 1 cat <&3 | grep -m 1 status | grep -m 1 UP
ERROR=$?

exec 3<&-
exec 3>&-

exit $ERROR
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to listen directly the 'master' realm.
Morover most recent Keycloak versions uses a different path (omitting 'auth'):

```
healthcheck:
  test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://0.0.0.0:8080/realms/master"]
  start_period: 10s
  interval: 30s
  retries: 3
  timeout: 5s
```

Answer (score 1):

One can also use the /health endpoint on the KeyCloak container as follows:

```
"healthCheck": {
  "retries": 3,
  "command": [
    "CMD-SHELL",
    "curl -f http://localhost:8080/health || exit 1"
   ],
   "timeout": 5,
   "interval": 60,
   "startPeriod": 300
 }
```